# Why are the edges in my conic-gradient not sharp?

Tags: css, pie-chart, css-gradients

I'm trying to create a sort of pie chart using CSS conic-gradients. I want each the transitions between wedges to be hard, rather than soft.

In pie1, below, the transitions are hard, but adding an extra wedge (as in pie2), makes all of the transitions soft.

Could anyone tell me why? And how to avoid this?

(I'm using Chrome 80 btw).

```css
.pie1 { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;  
    background: conic-gradient(
        #FF6666 11%, 
        #FF8080 11%, #FF8080 15%, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, 
  
        #FF9933 20%, #FF9933 27%,
        #FFB366 27%, #FFB366 31%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 31%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 35%,

        #996600 35%, #996600 42%,             
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 42%);
}

.pie2 { 
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;  
    background: conic-gradient(
        #FF6666 11%, 
        #FF8080 11%, #FF8080 15%, 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 20%, 

        #FF9933 20%, #FF9933 27%,
        #FFB366 27%, #FFB366 31%,
        rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 31%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 35%,

       #996600 35%, #996600 42%,   
       #FFC34D 42%, #FFC34D 47%,       
       rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 47%)
}
```

```html
<div class="pie1"></div>
<div class="pie2"></div>
```

[image: Image in Chome on Windows]

Comment: The edges look sharp to me (Chrome 80.0.3987.132), however as a pie-chart they look wrong as the segments do not fill the whole circle. Are you trying to create a 3D effect with the dark and light colour pairs? Can you screenshot what your page looks like.

Comment: I've added a screenshot taken from Chrome on Windows. Oddly when I use Chrome on Ubuntu, both pies are completely sharp.

Comment: Regarding the pie charts being incomplete - yes, this is just a code sample to show the blurring issue. In the event I gave up on the conic gradients and generated the chart using SVG.

Comment: I have the same problem now, but in microsoft edge on mac. In other browsers everything is sharp